# python - class instance variable inherence and class variable inherence

Tags: python, class, inheritance

The code below:

Since Iter Class is inheriting the Parser class, `class Iter(Parser):`

is it unnessary to define duplicate but Iter class specific variables with Parser class variables?

Meaning

`self.totalEntriesI` is just receiver of the variable value in the Parser class known as `totalEntires` shown in the code as `Parser.totalEntires` so that work may be done with the value.

however is this necessary?

could I achieve the same thing with out doing it

```
class Iter(Parser):


def __init__(self, Parser):

    self.totalEntriesI = Parser.totalEntries
    self.perPageI = Parser.perPage
    self.currentPageI = Parser.currentPage
```

Hugs and kisses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it's unneccesary. The class attributes ("variables") of `Parser` are also available on its subclass `Iter`.

If you assign them to instance attributes as shown, then each `Iter` instance will get its own copy of the values -- useful if you need to modify them later on a per-instance basis, but otherwise a waste of space and attention :)

A subtlety to be aware of: if you subsequently assign a value to one of these attributes via the subclass `Iter`, then `Iter` will get *its own copy* of the attribute. For example:

```
>>> class A():  my_attr = 'foo'
>>> class B(A): pass
```

As you'd expect,

```
>>> A.my_attr == B.my_attr == 'foo'
True
```

However, observe:

```
>>> B.my_attr = 'bar'
>>> B.my_attr
'bar'
>>> A.my_attr
'foo'
```